# Suggestion's on checking the syntax or arguments for a particular module/function

Tags: python

We all use python and its other modules on everyday basis. so when we are stuck with a particular module and its usage. And we want to find out what parameters are supported and passed to the a method

How do we find the usage of a particular class/module, the parameters passed/supported by it. Does everyone google the same or use the help on python ide? Some of the ide like pycharm doesn't display the whole argument list?

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
frame=Frame() -----> what arguments to pass to the Frame Class
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just look at the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are so so new using thinker, check this [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_frame.htm) with examples an explanaition, it will be really helpul to you

```
frame = Frame ( master, option, ... )
```

- master: This represents the parent window.
- options: Here is the list of most commonly used options for this widget. These options can be used as key-value pairs separated by commas.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good link for someone who just started programming few months back. Taking sometime to understand all tkinter classes/widgets.

Comment: great @Ary!, mark the answer as acepted if was useful to you :)

Comment: @Ary don't forget voting if you liked ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `help()` from any python shell.

```
from Tkinter import Frame
help(Frame)
```

`help` invokes the built-in help system. It is similar to `man` in linux.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for answer, really helpul :)